# Boost library setup for Codeblocks

Tags: c++, ide, codeblocks

How to use boost libraries with Codeblocks(Windows) ? What i need to do after downloading the library from boost site ? Any idea, suggestions, pointers ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the [instructions](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=BoostWindowsQuickRef) for setting up Boost with Code::Blocks

Comment: Thanks for the link. Can you tell me what is the build in that instruction page. I'm not sure about it. also what is boostjam in that page ? what is boostPro set up as well.

Comment: Boost Pro is a prebuilt distribution of Boost library with installer so you don't have to compile it yourself. Boost Jam is a tool for building Boost library (as it says in the wiki, it's unnecessary if you use Boost Pro). The build used in wiki is boost_1_37_0, but that doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i was looking for package like boostpro. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

For the header file only Boost classes (which is most of them), all you ned to do is to add the base of the Boost inclide directory to your project's include path. The directory will be called something like boost_1_37_0. You can then say things like:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
```

For the Boost facilitioes that acually require compiled libraries, you might want to take a look at http://nuwen.net/mingw.html which provides a complete MinGW environmemt including Boost and some other useful stuff.

Comment: there is so much explanation like build boost, compile boost thing going on some web site tutorials. Do i need to do all that to use boost ? I just downloaded the setup from boost site. i don't know how to proceed further.