# How to install the boost for CodeBlocks?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Boost library setup for Codeblocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008119/boost-library-setup-for-codeblocks)

I want to write a program using boost.
actually this is a program from webpage of Boost Getting Started.
it is :

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;

    std::for_each(
        in(std::cin), in(), std::cout << (_1 * 3) << " " );
}
```

when I built it, it gave me a list of errors:
error: boost/lambda/lambda.hpp: No such file or directory
error: 'boost' has not been declared
...
and what can I do for these errors? I mean how to set "Compiler and debugger" and "Global variables".

Comment: Copy the boost headers into your `include` folder.

Comment: Thanks. actually, I have done that. and more errors have appeared, error: boost/lambda/core.hpp: No such file or directory. I think I have not did the right thing to tell the compiler where to include the folder boost. and how can I fix it.

Comment: If the `boost` folder is located where the rest of your headers are, and all of the subdirectories like `boost/lambda` are there, it should work out.

Comment: thank you, I think this has worked out.

Comment: You can read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008119/boost-library-setup-for-codeblocks) first answer have link that you need.

Comment: That's cool. thank you, I had't known the webpage about codeblocks until you told me.